# send grid & parse 502 Bad Gateway with nginx

Tags: nginx, parse-platform, sendmail, sendgrid, digital-ocean

I am trying to migrate my parse application over to digital ocean and followed this guide :

```
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-parse-app-to-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04
```

Everything works perfectly fine until I get to the very end Test Parse Server ( Executing Example Cloud Code ) section

I tested the cloud code for the sample cloud code that was provided in the tutorial :

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {
  res.success('Hi');
});
```

so I got a Hi back in my browser as well as in postman. 
See image here : https://cloudup.com/cH2dbBx1KTo
￼
Then I test the function that uses sendgrid's service to send emails (http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-the-sendgrid-cloud-module/), my cloud code file looks like this :

see image : https://cloudup.com/cD6MNRP3Tft

and now I try to run my post request from postman and I get an error even on my hello function that was working before

See image : https://cloudup.com/cIkwJ6552_5

So I look around and figure out that its an issue with my sendgrid import

var sendgrid = require("sendgrid");
sendgrid.initialize(“xxxxxx”, “xxxxx.”);

in these lines.

does anyone have any experience with digital ocean cloud code and send grid emailing service please help me out I will be grateful as this is the last step left and I will be done with my migration :)

cheers
Tanzeel

Comment: are you sure this is not firewall error? Or did you set correctly the index.js (parse setup file)... in your case it is ecosystem.json

Comment: I have edited my question to include my ecosystem.json file too. I was able to make curl requests to my mongoDB instance from my home machine and it returned me with a result from that collection. At the moment those curl request are also returning me a 502 error

`Tanzeels-MacBook-Pro:eclipse trana$ curl -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: my app id here" https://test.pacecouriers.com/parse/classes/Drivers
`

`<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to specify server URL in parse config file. It is required and could be the reason why you cant run cloud code.

```
"PARSE_SERVER_URL": "http://localhost:1337/parse"
```

The url has be the same what you are using. There is also error in Nginx config in that tutorial, I explained it here https://serverfault.com/questions/765627/cannot-post-get-over-ssl/766428#766428

Comment: Yes this answer the you posted actually helped me get my POST and GET requests working :) and I was able to get data from my collections perfectly fine.  All the cloud code was working fine except for the send grrid function mentioned above. That function was sending back a 502 Bad Gateway, Then later on I kept trying and got a 301 parmanently moved and after this error non of my clound code works.

Comment: I am going to try from a fresh droplet and go over the whole process again including your link which was really helpful getting my GET and POST's working. I will log everything here. I think some sort of issue with sendgrid mailing is an issue or maybe a firewall. I will post my retry here soon. Thanks for the reply :) cheers

Comment: i would check the issues on github [https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sendgrid](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sendgrid)

Comment: Hey I am going to look into these issues for a solution. I updated my question and narrowed down to the root cause. it seems to be the sendgrid that is causing an issue.

Answer (score 1):

So I looked up at pm2 and to see real-time logs the command is

`pm2 logs`

at first when I ran the command I saw some errors, maybe they were there from before :

[image: documents_ _parse_pacecourier___root_ _ssh_root_159_203_35_195_ _179x47]

Then I tried the hello cloud function from postman app to test for its output in pm2 logs and I got  the following  :

[image: documents_ _parse_pacecourier___root_ _ssh_root_159_203_35_195_ _179x47]

Next I try to run my sendMail sendgrid function and I find out the the api-key I had used in my sendgrid function was throwing an error 
`ReferenceError: XXXXXXXXXXXX is not defined`

[image: documents_ _parse_pacecourier___root_ _ssh_root_159_203_35_195_ _179x47]

So I went back to my cloud code and used quotes around my api-key parameter and passed it as a string in my send grid initialize function. Then I retry and get

`[Error: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked]`

[image: documents_ _parse_pacecourier___root_ _ssh_root_159_203_35_195_ _179x47]

So I went back to my sendgrid account and made sure that the api-key I was using was the correct one and it seemed to be just fine. I tested again and got the same error again so I decided to generate a new api-key just in case.

So I realize that I was not using the api-key but instead API KEY ID :

[image: documents_ _parse_pacecourier___root_ _ssh_root_159_203_35_195_ _179x47]

When we create a new api-key on sendgrid they give us the actual api key once and they ask us to store it in some secure place :

`We can only display the key above one time. Please store it somewhere safe because as soon as you navigate away from this page, we will not be able to retrieve or restore this generated token.`

[image: documents_ _parse_pacecourier___root_ _ssh_root_159_203_35_195_ _179x47]

So after I used an actual api-key I was able to send emails

But one small issue still remains and I am not sure if its because of postman that I am using to run cloud code or something in the parse server or nginx that is still returning me with a 502 Bad Gateway as a response

[image: documents_ _parse_pacecourier___root_ _ssh_root_159_203_35_195_ _179x47]

But when I look at the logs for my parse server I do see a

`parse-wrapper-0 { message: 'success' }`

[image: documents_ _parse_pacecourier___root_ _ssh_root_159_203_35_195_ _179x47]

but it never gets back to me in my postman and instead I am getting a 502 error not sure why but the emails are being sent succesfully :)